# Deleted business account on Docusign and now unable to connect

Tags: docusignapi

I haven't change my code since yesterday but today I cannot connect and access my account with the same credentials. I am using the DocuSign REST API and I can access my account with the same credentials via Docusign website. 
I am following these code samples https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes

Edit:

This is not an issue with the Docusign API. Problem was I had two accounts. Business and developer with same email address. I deleted the business account and that affected my API connections

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you can provide more information regarding the problem you are facing. For ex: Which Docusign environment are you connecting to? Are you connecting to a specific API? What is the error message you are getting when you are connecting to the API?

Comment: I am having a general connectivity problem but for specifics the error message I am getting is "error calling webservice, status is:0". Again I have not change the code which was working yesterday so I do not think the mistake is on my end. And just to list a specific example https://github.com/docusign/docusign-rest-recipes/blob/master/polling_status_changes/polling_status_changes.php I am trying to access status values for my documents, which was working fine yesterday. I have my correct and valid email/password/integration key in place.

Comment: Have you tried making your request using Postman? Also, are you able to access this URL https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/service_information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some simple troubleshooting steps you can try to make sure there are no connectivity issues from your side.

**Step I: Check if the DocuSign API is up and running**

Access the following URL's in your browser and see if you are getting a 200 ok response. This should also return an XML containing the BuildVersion/LinkedSites/ServiceVersion

Sandbox: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/service_information

Production : https://www.docusign.net/restapi/service_information

**Step II: Check if your Account/Credentials are valid**

To validate you are providing the correct credentials, you can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to send a request to the [Authentication](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Authentication/Authentication/login/) api

```
Get https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information

Header: X-DocuSign-Authentication:
          { "Username":"developer@example.com",
            "Password":"********",
            "IntegratorKey":"[Your Integrator Key]" }
```

Comment: Thank you, I do have access to everything you listed. Problem was I had to accounts, business and developer with same email address. I deleted the business account and that affected my API connections (not website connections). Waiting for Docusign to resolve on their end.

Comment: Business end decisions. I am getting a live developer account and the account manager I discuss told me he opened a support case to resolve my demo account connectivity issues. I believe my Integrator Keys are disabled for access

Comment: Sounds good. Feel free to post new questions incase you encounter any new issues developing with the API.

Comment: I am still having problems, I get "error calling webservice, status is:0" with a fresh new developer account following the 'polling_status_changes.php' recipe. No word from Docusign support even though I opened a case to ask them about this. Anyway you can help? I do get 200 from Sandbox: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/service_information but Postman says my integratorKey is disabled or not found @CodingDawg